# How to use the Variable typed by the user in a For

Tags: c#

[image]
Currently I have a Text Box where the user enters a number and according to that number is the number of times that the cycle has to be repeated, but I do not know how to use the variable entered by the user within the condition of the For.
Any help?
I want to add the For in this part of my code

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
string x = "^XA^FO70,0^FS^FX Third section with bar code.^BY2,3,50^FO5,90^BC^FD123456789456744^FS^FX Fourth section(the two boxes on the 24bottom).^FO10,162^GB222,30,3^FS^CF0,20^FO15,170^FDREF:11905-01^FS^FO150,170^FDTALLA:24^FS^CF0,190^XZ";

            PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
            pd.PrinterSettings = new PrinterSettings();
            pd.ShowDialog(this);
            ;
            
            for (int es1=3; es1 < 5; es1++) 
                {
                   RawPrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(pd.PrinterSettings.PrinterName, x);                  
                }
                


        
        }
```

Comment: use `int.TryParse` to convert the string value and use that

Comment: @DanielA.White If that string in the question is the actual input, then OP won't get far with a simple `int.TryParse`. This looks like it needs thorough input sanitation.

Comment: @Andreas: There are a bunch of numbers in that input string ... which one do you need?

Comment: @Fildor That input string or string X is Zpl code that I send to the printer to print labels.

Comment: OK, then where's the user input here?

Comment: @Fildor I have a text box where the user types a number and that number is the variable I want to use in For, but when I do it I get different errors.

Comment: Ok, for starters: do not use a text box. Use a numerical input component. That will make things much easier for you. Starting with that its value will already be numerical.

Comment: And then: Can you show us, what exactly you have been trying and what the error was you got from that?

Comment: _"that's a good idea"_ - thanks :D - but that's a basic principle in UI: Deprive the user of possibilities to do something wrong. For example writing not-a-number in a field where you expect only numbers... It will make life easier for you and the user.

Comment: Actually I don't receive any error, since as you suggested I changed the text type, so there are no more problems on that part.

Comment: But I don't know how to make the cycle repeat as many times as the user has set, any suggestions?

Comment: If by "Cycle" you mean that loop: Let's say user input is 5: `for ( int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { ...}` And if you keep that input value in variable `int userCycle` then you could do `for ( int i = 0; i < userCycle; i++)` - just maybe check the value for being in a sane range. You wouldn't want it negative or 1000000000 I guess.

Comment: I get this error when changing UserCycle to the name of my numeric up down, it is the same error I was talking about before. Severity Code Code Description Project File Line Status suppressed
Error CS0019 Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'NumericUpDown'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Fildor already, use a numeric control like a NumericUpDown control or a custom version of a NumericUpDown to hide the spinner. Added benefit is you can control the min and max value the user can select.

[image]

Add the control to your project, compile, add an instance to your form. To get the current value us `AsInteger` property.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNamespaceGoesHere
{
    public class SpecialNumericUpDown : NumericUpDown
    {
        public SpecialNumericUpDown()
        {
            Controls[0].Hide();
            TextAlign = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
        }
        protected override void OnTextBoxResize(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            Controls[1].Width = Width - 4;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Provide access to value as an int from decimal
        /// </summary>
        [Browsable(false)] public int AsInteger => (int)Value;

        #region optional to stop beep on pressing enter

        public delegate void TriggerDelegate();

        public event TriggerDelegate TriggerEvent;
        protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == (Keys.Return))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
                e.SuppressKeyPress = true;

                TriggerEvent?.Invoke();

                return;
            }

            base.OnKeyDown(e);
        }

        #endregion

    }

}
```

Usage (CountNumericUpDown is the custom control)

```
private void CountButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int count = CountNumericUpDown.AsInteger;
    for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
    {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: i get this Error CS1061 "NumericUpDown" does not contain a definition for "AsInteger" nor an accessible extension method "AsInteger" that accepts a first argument of type "NumericUpDown" (is there a missing using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: Sounds like you didn't copy the custom control. See it [here](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/closet-code/blob/master/NumbersOnlyExample/Controls/SpecialNumericUpDown.cs) same as in my reply

Comment: I copied and pasted everything exactly the same :c

Comment: Did you adjust the namespace from YourNamespaceGoesHere to your's then rebuild the project, add the controlwhich will have a default name of specialNumericUpDown1 ?

Comment: I need to download something else to get the custom numericupdown?I think that's the part I'm confused about.

Comment: You need to add the control `SpecialNumericUpDown` to your project as mentioned in my first reply.

Comment: Then guide me a little more on how to add it, sorry for the inconvenience, I am still very new to this.

Comment: See [instructions](https://github.com/karenpayneoregon/closet-code/blob/master/NumbersOnlyExample/readme.md#use-in-your-project)